# Parsing google trends - JS object

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to get the search terms and their values in the rising table here:

http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cat=0-14&date=today%207-d&cmpt=q

I can't work out what html tag/class/path they're in. How can I work it out? I tried looking at the source code but it wasn't much help.

Any help is really appreciated - Thx! Antoine

Comment: The id is `trendsReportRisingSearches0`

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will return an array of arrays (the overarching array contains values for each table in the page). Each array element has an array where each table row is an object, broken down into it's 'term' and 'value'.

```
var tableValues = [];
var t = document.querySelectorAll(".trends-table-data");
if(t.length>0){
     var rows, row, cells, values;
     for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++){
          values = [];
          rows = t[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
          for(var r=0; r<rows.length; r++){
               row = rows[r];
               if(row.className.indexOf('trends-table-row')===-1) continue;
               cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
               values.push({
                   term: cells[0].innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''),
                   value: cells[1].innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
               });
          }
          tableValues[i] = values;
     }
     console.log(tableValues);
}
```

Since there are two tables on the page, the output for the page you're referencing is:

```
tableValues = [[{"term":"friv","value":"100"},{"term":"baby","value":"55"},{"term":"hot","value":"50"},{"term":"girls","value":"45"},{"term":"games","value":"45"},{"term":"juegos","value":"30"},{"term":"العاب","value":"25"},{"term":"love","value":"25"},{"term":"bible","value":"20"},{"term":"india","value":"20"}],[{"term":"sophiya haque","value":"Breakout"},{"term":"temple run 2","value":"+3,200%"},{"term":"крещение","value":"+700%"},{"term":"dear abby","value":"+450%"},{"term":"temple run","value":"+200%"},{"term":"amber heard","value":"+130%"},{"term":"plein champ","value":"+130%"},{"term":"paranormal activity 4","value":"+90%"},{"term":"scientology","value":"+70%"},{"term":"mama","value":"+60%"}]]
```